# CommandLine inside a loop

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using a gradle task which executes the command-line inside a file collection loop:

```
...
collection.each { file ->
        exec {
            workingDir = file(props['WORKING_DIR']).getAbsolutePath()
            commandLine "java", "-jar", file(props['SIGN_TOOL']).getAbsoluteFile(), file
        }
    }
...
```

Unfortunately, the gradle task ends up with this error:

> Execution failed for task ':signFiles'.
>
> > No signature of method: java.io.File.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: Possible
> >     solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure),
> >     any(groovy.lang.Closure), list()

How can i fix this issue?

Thx MVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've called your loop var `file` and then it's trying to use that for the call to `file()`...

Try renaming your closure variable:

```
collection.each { aFile ->
    exec {
        workingDir = file(props['WORKING_DIR']).getAbsolutePath()
        commandLine "java", "-jar", file(props['SIGN_TOOL']).getAbsoluteFile(), aFile
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have asked you earlier :D THANK YOU, SIR!